# How to put components in the middle of layouts

Tags: android, android-layout

How to put objects in the middle of the layouts.

In fact my problem is that the `android:layout_below` not worked when use `android:layout_centerInParent`

I want this:

[image: Wireframe]

** Update question **

My problem with code & image:

```
  <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/main_center_light" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtSearch" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" 
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bgSearch" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtSearch"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:text="Btn" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

I want EditText Exactly in the middle of light and the button below it
 but `android:layout_below` not worked! !!!

Comment: This is pretty easy to do. What have you tried so far. can you add the code.

Comment: @kapsym I tried so hard. This is not easy. Please try and give me the code if you succeed! I wanted to use `layout_below` But that does not work. I want the image to be exactly the middle.
Thank you.

Comment: `center_horizonal="true"`

Comment: @H.Brooks No. Please give me code. It does not work.When you try yourself, you understand that this is not easy. Thank you

Comment: If you post your code you will be more likely to get helped...

Comment: And I see in your picture that your `RelativeLayout` is `wrap_content` try setting it to `fill_parent` or `match_parent`

Comment: @H.Brooks Yes Problem solves with `match_parent`. But I want this with `wrap_content` !!

Comment: Why do you want your relative layout to be wrap content when you only have these 3 elements. How would then your relative layout stretch to height you need?

Comment: You can put the `wrap_content` - `RelativeLayout` inside a `match_parent` - `RelativeLayout`

Comment: Is your RelativeLayout doing something else apart from having these 3 elements?

Comment: @H.Brooks Question updated. Please see. thanks

Comment: @kapsym Question updated. Please see. thanks

Comment: If i use match_parent then  EditText is not in the middle of the light.

Comment: For this you need to have relativelayout as match parent. then the bottom part of your layout which contains multiple images has to be created inside that layout seperately using gridview or linear layout or whatever you prefer. and the remaining you can set using RL with match parent

Comment: Set the light image as background image of your relative layout. and then put edittext in center. Plus your button is also not below your edit text, it is above edittext

Comment: @kapsym RelativeLayout not have adjustViewBound :( it scaled

Comment: @kapsym RelativeLayout not have adjustViewBound :( it scaled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the combined rules in your layout don't work the way you're expecting. The root of the problem is the `wrap_content` height in your `RelativeLayout`, which is why the various comments keep telling you to change the height to something fixed.

Consider what information is needed for your `RelativeLayout` to actually lay itself out. Its height is `wrap_content`, so to know how tall it has to be, first it must lay out its children. However the positions of the children depend on the height of the `RelativeLayout`! The system will *try* to accommodate this, but it will often make what you would consider mistakes.

One way to fix the problem would be to avoid using `wrap_content` for your `RelativeLayout`'s height. It's hard to say whether or not there's a good way to do this without having all of the rest of your layout code.

Another way is to switch from `RelativeLayout` to `ConstraintLayout`. ConstraintLayout is essentially a better relative layout, and it turns out that it can handle this particular problem you're having.

The attributes you use are a little different. Instead of specifying `layout_below` you'd specify `layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf` (set my top to the bottom of this other view). And instead of `centerInParent` you use a combination of constraints that matches your view's edges to the parent view's edges. You can read all about `ConstraintLayout` here: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html

Here's your layout, redone as a `ConstraintLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/main_center_light"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtSearch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bgSearch"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Btn"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtSearch"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

(I don't have your images so I had to make something up on the fly... sorry the "light" image is so lame.)

Comment: Lol not everyone has the time to do this, this should be marked as correct, just for the effort!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/main_center_light" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtSearch" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" 
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bgSearch" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtSearch"              android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Btn" />
</RelativeLayout>
```